# How do I pass Perl arrays to/from SWIG?

Tags: perl, swig

In Perl, I'm accustomed to passing arrays to and from subs

```
sub abc {
  foreach my $x (@_) { print $x; }
  return (0, 1, 2);
}
```

How can I achieve similar behavior with SWIG'ed functions?

SWIG'ing this:

```
std::vector<int> print_list(std::vector<int> l)
{
  std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
  for(iter=l.begin(); iter!=l.end(); iter++) {
    printf("int %d\n", *iter);
  }

  return l;
}
```

Yields a sub that expects an array reference and returns an array reference? I'm using the stl templates that come with SWIG.

Do I need to write a typemap for this? Seems this would already be covered somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The typemap is already coded for you, but you still have to instantiate it.

As pointed in the [SWIG/STL doc](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_nn15), **you have to declare the `vector<int>` as a `vectori` and convert your Perl array to it**.

If you want to have a transparent convertion you have to code the typemap yourself.

*Code examples below, with your example*.

### print_list.hxx

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> print_list(std::vector<int> l);
```

### print_list.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

#include "print_list.hxx"

using namespace std;

vector<int> print_list(vector<int> l) {
    vector<int>::iterator iter;
    for(iter=l.begin(); iter!=l.end(); iter++) {
        printf("int %d\n", *iter);
    }
    return l;
}
```

### print_list.i

```
%module print_list
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_vector.i"

namespace std {
    %template(vectori) vector<int>;
    %template(vectord) vector<double>;
};


%{
#include "print_list.hxx"
%}


%include "print_list.hxx"
```

### test_print_list.pl

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;

use print_list;

my @row = (1, 2, 4);
my $vi = new print_list::vectori();
foreach my $val (@row) {
    $vi->push($val);
}

print Dumper(print_list::print_list($vi));
```

Comment: Does it remain same even for vector<string> ?

Comment: Also if i have to return a vector<int> from a c++ function and capture it in Perl as an array,u have code snippet for that?